# sigmoid function: an algebraic solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

if we have a sigmoid function $1/(1+e^a)$, where $a$ is in the form of $(x-b)/c$ and the sigmoid equals function a value, called $k$. This $k$ is in the form of $1/x^2$. So something like: $1/x^2= 1/(1+e^a)$ ,where $a = (x-b)/c$

Is it  possible to find a unique value for x algebraicelly?? And if not, why not?

It can be an approximation, but not a numerical one.

Edit: I had to use a numerical one :)
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have that
$$f(x)=\frac1{1+e^{\frac{x-b}{c}}}=k$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{C}$ then we can rearrange this to get
$$1+e^{\frac{x-b}{c}}=\frac1k$$
$$e^{\frac{x-b}{c}}=\frac1k-1$$
$$\frac{x-b}{c}=\ln{\left(\frac1k-1\right)}$$
$$x-b=c\ln{\left(\frac1k-1\right)}$$
$$x=b+c\ln{\left(\frac1k-1\right)}$$
Which is undefined for $k=0$ but otherwise allows a unique value of $x$ to be found.

Comment: thanks Peter! Can you see at my edit in the question? Seems that if $k = 1/x^2$, it is not possible to find a unique value for $x$ in a algebraic fashion?

Comment: No, I think you'll have to use numerical methods for that.

Comment: Peter, can the Lambert function help?

Comment: I tried with the Lambert-W function. I can't see any way to use it to help.

Comment: Peter, I eventually used the bisection method for it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are seeking an analytic solution to the equation
$$
\frac{1}{1+\exp((x-b)/c)} = 0,
$$
but the LHS is always positive for any $x$ since exponent is always positive, so both numerator and denominator are always positive.

However, as $x \to \infty$ if $c>0$ you will get the desired effect.